# No local network

Tags: networking

I have had this issue for a long time. All my devices (Raspberry Pi 2, Linux PC and a windows computer) return the public IP instead of the local IP after I write ifconfig/ipconfig. I don't think that it has anything to do with my devices because in a normal network they return the local IP. My router doesn't have an online interface. For example when I start the apache service (should only work on my local network) and try to access the site with a totally different PC in a different Network, it displays my site without a problem. I don't want to fix this issue because sometimes it is really usefull but I want to now why it is like this and if this kind of setup has a name or something. 
(I'm really sorry if my grammar is bad. My native language isn't english)

```
Ifconfig output:
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet CENS.ORED.244.47  netmask 255.255.254.0  broadcast CENS.ORED.245.255
        inet6 CENSORED:ba4c:4608  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether CENSORED:c0:0a:4d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 82868  bytes 6784569 (6.4 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 8075  bytes 4012067 (3.8 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

(I had to censor parts of it because it shows the public ip of my device and there are still some ports open which can be attacked and I don't want this to happen...)

inet should show the local ip but it shows my public IP! This happens with all my connected devices.

```
myip.is : CENS.ORED.244.47 (the same IP as inet shows...)
```

Comment: Why do you think you should not have a global IPv4 address on your device?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Should not every client on a home network have a local ip? It just seems really strange to me because on every other network you have a local IP but on this one not. Does this kind of "setup" (i don't know how it's called in english I hope you understand what I mean) have a name? I tried to do some research but I didn't find anything helpful...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of this? Your devices are not behind a NAT. The traffic is routed to the Internet, but without network address translation.

Usually a consumer-market router (home router) has a port labelled Internet/WAN/ISP. This port has a factory-configured NAT, so everything that goes out of it is masqueraded (that is, the port pretends there are no other devices on the LAN-side, that it is the originator of all the traffic).

Other routers (and switches) don't have a factory-configured NAT.

Beware. Each NAT is, by necessity, a basic firewall. If you don't use it, you need to take *much greater care to configure your firewall properly*. Firewall doesn't require any special division of IP addressing. There is no requirement to have special "local" or "private" addresses behind a firewall.